# PHP include specific file if screen is touch device?

Tags: javascript, php, mobile, touch

I can use javascript to determine if the screen is touch device, but I can't translate that to PHP in order to include a specific file.

```
<script>

function isTouchDevice() {
      return 'ontouchstart' in window || !!(navigator.msMaxTouchPoints);
}

if(isTouchDevice()) {
   document.getElementById('touch').value = 1;
} else {
   document.getElementById('touch').value = 0;
}


</script>
<body>
   <input type='hidden' id='touch' value='0'/>

<?php

  // This is where i need help 
  // and yes...i know the code below is not proper php its just what i want to achieve. 

   -- if ([touch screen is true]) then....
        include ("sections/blog_widget_mobile.php");
      else {
        include ("sections/blog_widget.php");
      }

?>
```

I can't find a php version of the javascript function isTouchDevice(), so i thought the best way would be to apply a value to an html element and try to retrieve that value via php.

Can anyone help?

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: jQuery Load: if(touchScreen) { $( "#result" ).load( "sections/blog_widget_mobile.php" ); } else { $( "#result" ).load( "sections/blog_widget.php" ); }

Comment: navigator.msMaxTouchPoints is Microsoft only and is being removed in IE 11 per this MS document http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772144%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Xaxd jquery has a built in function touchscreen? Is this JQuery or JQuery Mobile? I'm not using jQM

Comment: @bagofmilk load is standard jquery. use standard javascript to detect touchscreen: <script>var touchScreen = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;</script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery to load the files dynamically. Use javascript to detect for ontouchstart.

```
<script>
if('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) { 
    $(document.body).load( "sections/blog_widget_mobile.php" ); 
} else { 
    $(document.body).load( "sections/blog_widget.php" ); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is interesting, but I have to load the php file at a specific point in the file. If i use this, then it will only load the php file and not all of the other "includes" i have in my index.php

Comment: you can replace "document.body" with the div id of the part of the index you wish to load the blog widget.

Comment: ie $("#blogwidget").load( "sections/blog_widget_mobile.php" ); 

would load the blog_widget_mobile into the <div id='blogwidget'></div>

Answer (score 0):

Even if I wouldn't recommend this:

If you really need to include specific PHP-Files (e.G. execute an additional SQL-Query for touchscreen users), you could test if the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`-variable contains one of a few - often used - strings for mobile user agents.
[This List](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) could help you.

Of course, you'll manually need to find these (there are many different User-Agents!) and update it from time to time. Some users will probably not be registered as "touch device user", mainly if they use unusual browsers.